# Is it possible to restore a MongoDB database from a .bson file quicker than mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongorestore

I have a very huge database from an old backup. It's about 500GB total and it's a .bson file. At the current rate of my harddrive and CPU, I am done in probably 10-20 hours. EDIT: About 9 hours.

I simply ran:

```
mongorestore -d database -c collection C:\very_large_backup.bson
```

Is it possible for MongoDB to simply access the .bson file directly, or is `mongorestore` the only option I have?

I plan on moving to a Microsoft SQL Server with this data (discarding the extra bits of information that might overlap). Maybe there's a faster way that way?

Comment: `mongorestore` is the only option if you want to load it into MongoDB. If you just want to extract the documents, you can use `bsondump`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/bsondump/

Comment: if you are savvy with python, consider a library I use to to access .bson files directly when required to integrate with other systems.  https://github.com/bauman/python-bson-streaming